# django-admin makemessages --no-obsolete doesn't seem to be working

Tags: django, django-admin, django-management-command, makemessages

First of all, I am expecting `--no-obsolete` would comment out `msgid` and `msgstr` if `gettext` is deleted, right?

How I am testing is:

1. I wrote `gettext("some string here")` in view
2. I ran `makemessages` command
3. It wrote a `.po` file as expected
4. Then I deleted `gettext()` line from view and saved file, verified `runserver` working.
5. I ran `makemessages --no-obsolete` and it has not made any changes to `.po` file.

`.po` file content extract .

```
#. Translators: This message is a test of wrap line
#: servers/views.py:31
msgid "Do let me know if it works."
msgstr ""
```

**dev environment**

> Django =  1.11
>   OS = Mac/Ubuntu 14.04

**settings.py**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE = (
      os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "locale"),
)
```

Comment: Can you please also add your environment setup? What Django version? Which OS are you using?

Comment: @TarunLalwani please see updates

Comment: Can you please also add you `settings.py` file?

Comment: What specifically from settings file? I haven't changed anything from default settings.

Comment: All locale related stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now with the help of Julien and Tarun, I found following observations.

`python manage.py makemessages -l <locale>`

If there is no `gettext` in the file being processed, the above command won't `write/update` `.po` file. That means if the corresponding `.po` file earlier had entries for `msgstr` and `msgid`, then it won't remove those entries unless file being processed had at least one `gettext`.

> Note: Above behavior is irrespective of `--no-obsolete`

**Now to make the `--no-obsolete` work as expected we need to follow the steps below.**

1. First thing run `python manage.py makemessages -l <locale>`, this would write `.po` file with `msgid` and `msgstr`.
2. Now set `msgstr` and run `python manage.py compilemessages -l <locale>`. This command writes `.mo` file in the same directory as `.po` file.
3. Now next time when you run `makemessages` again (**without --no-obsolete**), `.po` and `.mo` files are compared and missing/deleted `gettext` are commented in `.po` file.
4. And when you run `makemessages --no-obsolete`, commented entries are removed from the `.po` file.

`E.g`

if you have 3 `gettext` entries, and you run `makemessages` first time, it would write 3 `msgid` and 3 `msgstr` in `.po` file. Now if you remove all `gettext` entries, `.po` file won't be updated after you run `makemessages` again, but if your keep at least 1 `gettext` entry in same file and  run `makemessages` again, it would delete all `msgid` and `msgstr` for deleted `gettext` entries.

But if you run `compilemessages` after  `makemessages`, `.mo` file is created and then for subsequent `makemessages` commands `.po` and `.mo` files are compared and then `msgid` and `msgstr` is commented in `.po` file for deleted `gettext` entries.

Then finally when you run `makemessages` with `--no-obsolete` option the commented messages from `.po` files are deleted permanently.

Answer (score 3):

What the --no-obsolete does is to run a command called msgattrib with the --no-obsolete option on the content the po file. A typical case would be you generate your po file with makemessages, you get this:

```
#: servers/views.py:31
msgid "Do let me know if it works."
msgstr ""
```

Then you translate:

```
#: servers/views.py:31
msgid "Do let me know if it works."
msgstr "translation"
```

Then you remove the gettext entry, it'll still by default keep the translation, but mark it as obsolete.

```
#: servers/views.py:31
#~msgid "Do let me know if it works."
#~msgstr "translation"
```

If you set --no-obsolete option, then once your po file is done, it'll run msgattr with no-obsolete option. This will remove lines tagged with #~. See https://linux.die.net/man/1/msgattrib

But, the way makemessages is built, is that this will be called once the po file is written. But if there are no gettext in the files being processed, then it won't write to the po file. It'll just stop before getting to this msgattrib command. The po file you see is the one generated by the previous makemessages command. So the no-obsolete won't do anything.

There's no real solution to this. the no-obsolete option doesn't deal with the cases where you don't have any gettext to process.

Comment: What do I need to do exactly to get the `--no-obsolete` effect?

Comment: You need to still have a gettext somewhere

Comment: I tried to have another gettext in same file in another view.  No effect

Comment: @JulienGrégoire, I just test this on my laptop and your observation doesn't seem to be true.  When I ran with `--no-obsolete` the data was actually deleted from the `po` file. Without `--no-obsolete` it gets commented like `#~` and with `--no-obsolete` it removes the string from the file

Comment: @TarunLalwani can you please list down the steps/process?

Answer (score 1):

So I think @JulienGrégoire was right about the fact that if there is no translation processed then the `--no-obsolete` won't work. There needs to be at least one translation captured for `--no-obsolete` to work.

But the solution to this quite simple. You can update your `settings.py` to define `LANGUAGES` like below

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
)
```

Now your `settings` will always generate a translation. So it will make sure that you get `--no-obsolete` working every time you use it

Comment: Tarun, Can you write the steps, please? Or confirm that, the steps I have mentioned in the question are right.

Comment: and Yes, the `LANGUAGES` is there in my setting. I forgot to add here.

Comment: Do you use the `_` like I did in the `LANGUAGES` value?

Comment: yes. I do. but only settings. in views I used `gettext` only

Comment: Please run like this `python manage.py makemessages --no-obsolete --all` and see if it helps. I have tested with both `gettext` and `_` and it works fine for me

Comment: I have tested 1.11 and 2.00 and both work fine with this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167150/discussion-between-kishor-pawar-and-tarun-lalwani).